# How to filter data by second parent?

Tags: django

I have three models(A,B,C). A<-B<-C. C is child of B, B is child of A.

How to filter all C's where is A=something?

Comment: `C.objects.filter(b__a=something)`?

Comment: Just one thing: if i had and D like this: D<-A<-B<-C. To get C's related to D i must do C.objects.filter(b__a__d=something)? or can simplier?

Comment: Yes, you have to walk through the relations